# Remove inner points from collinear List

Tags: computational-geometry

Imagine a List of Points that is collinear:

```
{{-1,-1},{1,1},{0,0},{-2,-2},{1,1}}
```

How can I at first check, if such a List is collinear and if so, reduce it to contain only the two "endpoints":

```
{{1,1},{-2,-2}}
```

---

### Edit

If a list is not collinear, I'd expect to get the untouched list back.

```
{{-7,-1},{1,1},{0,0},{-2,-2},{1,1}} -> {{-7,-1},{1,1},{0,0},{-2,-2},{1,1}}
```

---

### Approaching

```
pnts = {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {1, 1}};
totals = Total /@ pnts
list = Pick[pnts, totals, Min[totals] | Max[totals]]
DeleteDuplicates[list //. {} -> Sequence[]]
```

gives the Endpoints of a collinear set, but how could I apply a check for collinearity first (see my edit)?

Comment: After seeing multiple failures of the built-in computational geometry functions applied to your numeric values I am inclined to ask: are your values precise or floating point numeric, and if they are FP what tolerance should be used to determine collinearity?

Comment: `Sort[DeleteDuplicates[coLine]][[{-1, 1}]]`

Comment: `If[MatrixRank[Transpose[#]] <= 1, Sort[#][[{1, -1}]], #] &` should to the trick...

Comment: @ciao looks good, how would I apply that to my `pnts`? If it works, I think ist worth posting an answer :)

Comment: `myFn=
 
If[MatrixRank[Transpose[#]] <= 1, Sort[#][[{1, -1}]], #] &;` then to use it, `myFn@pnts`...

Comment: @ciao Very nice!  `MatrixRank` even supports a `Tolerance` option to address my concern.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I calculate my point lists from a `RotationTransform`. If that function returns precise values, the rest of my calculations should also be precise. But I'm not quite sure about that...

Comment: @ciao It seems to work quite good! I encourage you to put your solution into an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sturdier variation of ciao's answer:

```
getEnds[pts_?MatrixQ] := If[MatrixRank[Standardize[pts, Mean, 1 &]] ==
                            Last[Dimensions[pts]], pts, 
                            With[{dm = DistanceMatrix[pts]}, 
                                 pts[[FirstPosition[Unitize[dm - Max[dm]], 0]]]]]
```

Tests:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["collinearity"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            n = 30;
            init = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2];
            d = RandomReal[4]; θ = RandomReal[{-π, π}];
            pos = RandomReal[1, n];
            tst = Transpose[{init, init + d Through[{Cos, Sin}[θ]]}.{1 - pos, pos}];
            ends = getEnds[tst];
            Graphics[{{Red, Point[tst]}, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[ends]}}]]
```

[image: 2D collinear points]

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["collinearity"];
            n = 30;
            init = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 3];
            d = RandomReal[4]; θ = RandomReal[{-π, π}]; φ = RandomReal[π];
            pos = RandomReal[1, n];
            tst = Transpose[{1 - pos, pos}] .
                  {init, init + FromSphericalCoordinates[{d, φ, θ}]};
            ends = getEnds[tst];
            Graphics3D[{{Red, Point[tst]}, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[ends]}}]]
```

[image: 3D collinear points]

Comment: (Of course, you will need to do a few replacements for versions earlier than 10.)

Answer (score 4):

Posting this less-than-efficient method just for the fun of it

Say you've got a list of random collinear points

```
SeedRandom[42];
ln = InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, {2, 2}]];
pts = RandomPoint[
   ln,
   50, {{-1000, 1000}, {-1000, 1000}}];
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@pts, Blue, Thick, ln}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now these are only approximate numbers, so they are *approximately* collinear.  In order to get the `MatrixRank` test to work, I have to set the `Tolerance` up to 0.4

```
MatrixRank[pts, Tolerance -> .3]
MatrixRank[pts, Tolerance -> .4]
(* 2 *)
(* 1 *)
```

So here's a silly modification to ciao's solution that determines if the areas of triangles are zero in the list,

```
myFn2 = If[
   PossibleZeroQ@*Chop@*Area@*Triangle /@ Partition[#, 3, 2] // 
    Apply[And], Sort[#][[{1, -1}]], #] &
```

and it works on this example

```
myFn2@pts
(* {{-997.106, 457.397}, {829.276, -995.571}} *)
```

and in higher dimensions,

```
SeedRandom[42];
ln = InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, {2, 3}]];
pts = RandomPoint[
   ln,
   50, {{-1000, 1000}, {-1000, 1000}, {-1000, 1000}}];
Graphics3D[{Blue, ln, Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@pts, Yellow, 
  PointSize[.1], Sphere[#, 50] & /@ (myFn2@pts)}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it isn't guaranteed to work -

> The general problem of determining whether an expression has value zero is undecidable; [`PossibleZeroQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) provides a quick but not always accurate test

### Version 9 compatible

For version 9 I couldn't use any of my favorite functions. We can't use the operator forms of anything, nor can we use `Area` or `Triangle`, so we can resort to taking the determinant of a matrix as described [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html)

```
myFn2V9[pts_] := If[Max[
    (Chop[Det[Map[(Append[#, 1] &), #]], 10^-8] &) /@ 
       Partition[#, 3, 2, 1, {First@#}] &@pts
    ] == 0,
  Sort[pts][[{1, -1}]], pts]
```

Comment: Thats a cool view on it :)

Comment: I have MA 9.0.1 and I cannot run your code, any idea why? Is it possible to make it compatible with older versions, I would be interested to compare performances of your and my codes.

Answer (score 2):

```
col[pts_] := 
  Module[{a},
    a = MapThread[Append, {pts, ConstantArray[1, Length[pts]]}];
    If[Length[NullSpace[a]] == Last[Dimensions[pts]] - 1, Sort[pts][[{1, -1}]], pts]]
```

It turns out that `NullSpace` is rather slow. One can replace `Length[NullSpace[a]]==Last[Dimensions[pts]] - 1`with `MatrixRank[a] == 2`. For this my acknowledgements fully go to @ciao. In fact his initial answer only required two minor correction that I am realising here.

```
colFast[pts_] := 
 Module[{a = MapThread[Append, {pts, ConstantArray[1, Length[pts]]}]},
  If[MatrixRank[a] == 2, Sort[pts][[{1, -1}]], pts]]
```

Now timing results comparing with the method of @JasonB.

```
listN = Table[
  test = Table[{8. - 5. i, -7. i}, {i, k}]; 
  {k,myFn2V9[test] // Timing // First, 
   k,colFast[test] // Timing // First}, {k, 100000,1000000, 100000}]
gr = ListLinePlot[{listN[[All, 1 ;; 2]], listN[[All, 3 ;; 4]]}, 
           AxesLabel -> {"# points", "time (s)"}, PlotLegends -> {myFn2V9, colFast}]
```

[image]

It seems that both methods do feature linear scaling, albeit with different prefactors.

Answer (score 1):

*Historical note:*

[image]

If the coordinate entries were all integers, the `CollinearPoints` function would come in handy replacing the rank calculations featured in other answers. However, such is rarely the practical case.

---

Let's define a function `f` and use it on two examples on the page:

```
f[k_List] := 
 If[NumericQ@RegionMeasure@ConvexHullMesh[k], k, 
  SortBy[k, First][[{1, -1}]]]
```

---

*Explanation:*

The idea is that if a `ConvexHullMesh` can be created with the given `pts` and its `RegionMeasure` returns a numeric quantity, then the points are non-collinear. A further check can be introduced (if required) regarding an upper threshold on the magnitude of this area. If the calculation returns unevaluated, then the points are collinear (barring any symbolic inputs). In this case, the two extreme points are extracted.

---

**Ex:1**

```
pts = {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {-2, -2}, {1, 1}};
f@pts
```

> {{-2, -2}, {1, 1}}

**Ex:2** (from @JasonB, featuring real numbers)

```
SeedRandom[42];
ln = InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1000, 1000}, {2, 2}]];
pts = RandomPoint[ln, 50, {{-1000, 1000}, {-1000, 1000}}];

f@pts
```

> {{-997.106, 457.397}, {829.276, -995.571}}